# TFSPreview.com and Azure continuous deployment for multiple solutions in TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-deployment

I recently tried out Microsoft's TFS-in-the-cloud service (TFSPreview.com) and felt the TFS team finally 'gets it'. TFSPreview.com might switch us from GIT+bug tracker+powershell as the integrated workflow actually works (continuous deployment is GREAT!).

Well, almost. Our "one project" test on TFSPreview.com works great for continuous deployment but our 'real' source controls looks like

```
Root
\--Solution1
   \--ProjectA(IIS)
   \--ProjectB(IIS)
\--Solution2
   \--ProjectC(AzureWebRoleProject)
```

***Question:*** How can I express the following to TFSPreview.com/Azure's portal/VS2012?

- Everything in root must be version controlled in TFS
- But only ProjectC should be enrolled in Azure's continuous deployment

Continuous deployment currently tries to deploy *the entire root* to Azure and sure enough, fails. On a side note, it would be nice if they enabled continuous deployment for GIT for Azure Cloud services too (not just for Azure Web sites as right now)

Thanks
Sid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something that has actually been discussed via the online forums at the [TFS Deployment to Windows Azure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuretfs/threads) forums.

Specifically, a MS representative has indicated that this is currently not supported (see [Continuous deployment with multiple cloud projects in solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuretfs/thread/7409aed1-a58a-4f24-ae44-0434b41d693f)), but is something that they need to provide a solution for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible workaround that will make you feel like bathing.

```
Root
\--Solution2
   \--ProjectC

Root-Branch
\--Solution2
   \--ProjectC
\--Solution1
   \--ProjectA
   \--ProjectB
```

- *Only the main branch (Root) appears to be deployed on check-in.*
- Merge to Root when you want to deploy.
- Never merge Solution1 back to Root.