# Azure continuous deployment for a specific project inside a solution

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I'm trying to set up a build definition for a solution that has multiple web projects in it, but I want a specific one to be deployed as a result of a build (as far as I understand it takes the first web project). I know that there has been discussions around that issue but these discussions are quite old now. I wonder if there is still no solution.

Comment: I've also had a look at this problem, and I think this still is an issue. You can read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749718/tfspreview-com-and-azure-continuous-deployment-for-multiple-solutions-in-tfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [customizing deployments using a .deployment file](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments)

Basically to achieve what you want you would need to create a `.deployment` file in the root of your repo that contains something like the following

```
[config]
project = MyOtherWebProject/MyOtherWebProject.csproj
```

Comment: This example is using Git as source control, do you think the same can be achieved with team foundation source control?