# Azure Websites Continuous Delivery

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, continuous-delivery

I have a solution in Visual Studio Team Services that has 2 Web Applications (specifically one project for WebAPI services and another for the actual site using MVC).

I'm trying to set up continuous delivery to Azure but all the information that I can find seems to assume that you only have a single Web Application within your solution (which seems a little unrealistic for all but the simplest of projects!).

The out of box continuous delivery process seems to just pick and deploy the first Web Application it finds (which isn't necessarily the same project each time!)

I've tried specifying the Deployment Settings file, but that seems to affect the destination rather than the project being deployed since again, it seems to just "pick" a project to deploy, and each time it deploys every single compiled assembly plus all dependencies rather than just the binaries and dependencies of the project actually being deployed, which can cause issues with MVC finding duplicate controller matches for a given name (this can of course be fixed by specifying the namespace of the controllers within the route configuration, but that seems less than ideal, and still doesn't fix the entire problem).

Ideally I'd like to find a way to deploy both projects with a single build, but as a temporary solution I'd be happy with 2 builds that are both triggered by a check-in of the single solution, that each reliably deploy 1 of the 2 Web Applications.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I guess I could write my own custom build template, but I'm hoping there is an easier answer (not least because I can't imagine that this isn't a problem being faced by other people!)

I did find this question [TFSPreview.com and Azure continuous deployment for multiple solutions in TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749718/tfspreview-com-and-azure-continuous-deployment-for-multiple-solutions-in-tfs) but since that's quite old and is specifically talking about AzureWebRoleProjects rather than Web Applications being deployed to the newer Azure Websites feature, I'm hoping that there is a more positive answer?

Comment: Afraid there is no easy unswer. I've tried multiple things and nothing simple is available for that. You'll have to implemenet web-deploy process that delivers one project and than another one. I presume you'd like to deploy to `/` the MVC app and to `/api` WebApi project?

Comment: I have the same setup, and resorted to using a Powershell script to run web deploy via the TFS build definition.

Comment: @trailmax I was actually intending to deploy each site to a separate WebSites instance, but deploying the WebApi project to an /api subfolder would also work. Disappointed there looks to be no "official" solution, given that it feels like it could be fixed with a new build template, I'm surprised that MS haven't created one!

Comment: uh, if that 2 different web-sites, that can be easier. Is TFS under your control? or is that Visual Studio Online?

Comment: @trailmax Visual Studio Online...

Comment: that can be problematic. I was thinking you can build a web-deploy package for one project, deploy it with powershell, build a web-deploy package for another project and deploy it to a different site with powershell again. But not sure how VSO will allow to execute powershell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with multiple build configurations. In addition to Debug and Release you could specify two more, one for each app.

You can find these in Visual Studio at Build -> Configuration Manager. And then in the configurations specify only one of them to be built. Then running MSBuild with that configuration will output only one WebDeploy package.